# Is it possible to do except for the same error several times ? Socket library timeout

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I'm trying to do a timeout function on socket, and I am unable to except it past one time. Is there anyway to do this in python?  I thought about a while loop, but I still would need to recognize the exception as timeout will still throw an error. Any suggestions?

```
except socket.timeout as a:
    print("We ran out of time!")
    print("Attempt 2 of 3...")
    data, _ = clientSocket.recvfrom(2096)
    clientSocket.settimeout(2)

except socket.timeout as b:
    print("Oh no, we couldn't find it again!")
    print("Attempt 3 of 3...")
    data, _ = clientSocket.recvfrom(2096)
    clientSocket.settimeout(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written is incorrect, because every `except` must coordinate with a `try`.  I think you want something like this pattern:

```py
MAX_ATTEMPTS=4
attempts = 0
while attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS:
    try:
        do_stuff()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        attempts += 1

if attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS:
    raise MyCustomException(f"Failed to do stuff within {MAX_ATTEMPTS} attempts")
```

I don't know what the rest of your code is, btw, but I *strongly* suspect `socket.timeout` is not actually an exception and can't be caught.  It looks more like a value (the timeout for the socket).